# How to set UIButton style to a particular UITableViewCell without changing other cells programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `FlagButton` which extends `UIButton`. I have added this to a `UITableCell`. On tap on the button I want to change the background color, but only for the button in that cell. Currently it is change color for other cells as well.

```
class FlagButton: UIButton {
    // ..

    func initStyle() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.setTitle("foo", for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown), for: .touchDown)
    }

    @objc func touchDown() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

```
class PostViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var flagBtn: FlagButton?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        flagBtn = FlagButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 20))
        guard let flagBtn = flagBtn else { return }
        flagBtn.initStyle()
        contentView.addSubview(flagBtn)
    }
}
```

```
// ..
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = latestTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but the `guard` line is pointless. `flagBtn` does clearly have a value. That's the case where an implicit unwrapped optional is recommended: `var flagBtn: FlagButton!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the button gets changed for others cells is that UITableView is reusing cells. So the cell, in which button background was changed, is reused again later in the function `latestTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell`

You need to keep track of which cell was changed. And in your `dequeueReusableCell` function, check if it's the same cell, then change the background for UIButton otherwise make it normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.oneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.oneTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.twoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.twoTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
    }

    func oneTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("Tapped")
    }

    func twoTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("Tapped")
    }
}
```